# Numeric Timestamp date diff calculation

Tags: sql, pycharm, sql-timestamp

I tried calculating in Pycharm sql the diff between two different columns of
start timestamp
end timestamp
I tried using TIMESTAMPDIFF func but sql doesn't recognize the different date segments 'second' 'minute' etc.

any ideas?